# Assign default value to route parameter in Slim

Tags: php, routes, slim

Let's say, I have

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function($name){
  echo 'Hello' . $name;
});
```

Is it possible to have default value for `$name` so if I just go to

```
http://myurl.com/hello
```

*without second segment, it will out put

> Hello default

If yes, How to do that ? **How to assign default value to route parameter in Slim ?**

I know there is [Optional Route Parameter](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters), but I'm not sure to use it since it's still experimental.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I've tested it. I works well.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello(/:name)', function ($name = 'default') {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

You can visit like this:

```
http://slim.test.com/hello
http://slim.test.com/hello/srain
```

*can not* visit like this:

```
http://slim.test.com/hello/
```

#### update: If you want to make both of them can be visited:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/hello(/)(/:name)', function ($name = 'default') {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: should use this router: `/hello/(/:name)`, they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `default parameters`.

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function($name="default"){
  echo 'Hello' . $name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function($name){
  if (empty($name)){
    $name='default';
  }
  echo 'Hello' . $name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue wherein I had to handle an optional parameter in the request. Try this I have tested it myself.

```
$app->get('/hello(/:name)',function($name="default"){
  echo 'Hello' . $name;
});
```